# Cucumber scenario with quotes in the text

Tags: cucumber

I'd like to have quotes in my scenario data.  It's not working when that data has quotes in it.  An example modified from The Cucumber Book would be:

```
Then I should see the "<message>" message

 Examples:
 | type | message |
 | Swiss | I love Swiss cheese |
 | Blue | I love "Blue" cheese |
 | Cheddar | I love Cheddar cheese |
```

In my particular case I get an undefined step definition message because of "Blue" in the second scenario above.  Is there a way I should be escaping the quotes?  (I've tried backslashes but that didn't make any difference.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that your current step definition looks like:

```
Then /I should see the "([^"]+)" message/ do |message|
    p message
end
```

The `[^"]` tells the regex to match anything except double-quotes. This would be why your "Blue" example does not match.

Given that you are only looking for one argument, it would be safe to do:

```
Then /I should see the "(.*)" message/ do |message|
    p message
end
```

Using `(.*)` would match everything between the quotes, including the quotes around Blue.

Comment: Thank you, your observation about the step definition was spot-on.