# Pass arguments with double quotes string to steps

Tags: go, cucumber, gherkin

I have the following `Scenario` defined:

```
Scenario: test
    When test starts
    Then check data with '{"age":"18","gender":"male"}'
```

Then try to pass `{"age":"18","gender":"male"}` to the step:

```
func FeatureContext(s *godog.ScenarioContext) {
    s.Step(`^check data with "([^']*)"$`, checkDataWith)
}

func checkDataWith(data string) error {
    return godog.ErrPending
}
```

It says the step is not impelmented, looks like the `{"age":"18","gender":"male"}` is not passed correctly, how to pass parameter like `{"age":"18","gender":"male"}` to step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helped me on the other case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19257196

In your case you can try to:

```
func FeatureContext(s *godog.ScenarioContext) {
    s.Step(`^check data with '(.*)'$`, checkDataWith)
}

func checkDataWith(data string) error {
    return godog.ErrPending
}
```

So the data will be passed to your scenario in the way it was in the step description:

```
{"age":"18","gender":"male"}
```